# jQueryMobile page transition on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a project using jQm, Phonegap for Android app. I have a issue with page transitions. It is flickering when change page, I found a lot of solution but nothing work

These are solutions I found

- data-transition="none" / $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
- .ui-page { backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
- delete meta.attr( "content", disabledZoom ); & meta.attr( "content", enabledZoom ); in jquery.mobile.js
- -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
- < meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>

  So, what should i do? I using phonegap 2.9.0, jQm 1.3.2, backboneJS, requireJS, jQuery 1.9 and tested on Android 2.3.6

Comment: what problem you are facing , i.e flickering or else

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it is flickering.

Comment: You should post your code

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
                    {
                       if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1)
                       {
                         $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
                         $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
                       }
                    });
                    </script>
                    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```